# Why Linear Layout come every time with the Listview?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app in android studio. I have a XML file songlist.xml. There is two Layout one is Relative and other Linear Layout both is inside the Constrain Layout. Here is code=>

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#262626"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textColor="#ef66dd"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="333dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="409dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ok.. The TextView is appended dynamically by java to show the list of all the songs but the main problem is the ImageView come after the everysong i.e if I have 10 songs in the list then the image(in Linear Layout) is shown 10 times below the song.

The code of java is given below:-

```
final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
items = new String[mySongs.size()];
for(int i=0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){

    items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","");

}

ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.songllist,R.id.textView, items);
lv.setAdapter(adp);
```

here is the screen shot of my app on my smartphone
[App on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBBnw.png)

As you can see the image in the LinearLayout come every time with a song.
I want LinearLayout should be bottom and not show every time with a song like this :- 
[Desire Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o96Pa.png)

I have tried many things like create other layout and then include that layout in this layout but did not work. If anyone have idea what is the problem please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a layout file that describes the whole screen and a layout file that describes just one list **element**. You have put the image into the layout file for a list element, so the image will appear for every list element, as it should. To show the image only once, put it into the layout for the whole screen, that contains your list.

Comment: can you please give more detail of your answer. I didn't understand :P

Comment: And there is two layout one for list element and other for image. I don't know why image is repeat every time listView repeats